# Can't Find Management IP Address of Wireless Access Point

Tags: router

I have a wireless G access point in a central location in the house and I have had wireless disabled on my router.  My router supports N (2.4 ghz version) so I recently decided to put N up. I want to log into my access point so that I can make sure the channels are not the same but I cannot remember the IP address I assigned it.

Are there any programs that will search the network and find all IP addresses that are used and what device those IP addresses belong to?

Comment: ServerFault is not the right place for this - please read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq). Your question is also lacking the details required to answer you question (e.g, it's not clear how many access points you have and which one you can't find the IP address for). Additionally, if I correctly understood your question this ground has already been covered here: [Find IP address of a device?](http://serverfault.com/questions/153971/find-ip-address-of-a-device).

Comment: reset the configuration on the AP to the factory default, then you'll know the IP addy. Might want to write it down this time. Further, N takes up 60Mhz of the 100Mhz available in 2.4GHz-only mode (meaning if you don't pick channel 1 or 12 for the primary channel, you may be taking up the whole 2.4GHz spectrum; some of your neighbors may hate you for this, I have encountered this situation). If you put one AP on channel 1 the other on 12, you'll be taking up the whole 2.4GHz spectrum, see previous comment about your neighbors hating you and possibly plotting ways to cause harm to your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a free tool called [Advanced IP Scanner](http://www.radmin.com/products/ipscanner/).  Download it to your PC and run a scan.  It will give you a list of every device with an IP address. For a small network, the scan will take just a couple of minutes. You should be able to figure it out from the info provided.  Worst case, you browse to the devices that have HTTP open and figure it out from there.

Alternatively (and not a specific answer to your question), you can use the [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) freeware to examine the wireless signals around you.

Answer (score 0):

Log into the router - it will have a device list with device names and their respective IP addresses, including your wireless G AP.

Comment: If you're referring to a DHCP client list, then that depends on the AP getting its address through DHCP.. which it might not be.  I don't think I've ever come across a consumer router that has an ARP list in the web UI..

Comment: I've never come across one that _Doesnt_ have a 'device list' (not a DHCP lease list)

Comment: A list of associated wifi clients, certainly.  But that does no good when looking for a device that's connected over copper..

Answer (score -1):

When you are connected to your router look at your default route.  This should be the ip address of your AP.  How you do this will vary based on your OS.

Comment: -1 .. this is not likely correct.  More likely the AP has an IP for management, but is acting in pass through mode, and the wireless device gets the router as the default gateway.

Comment: Although that is possible I don't see how you can derive that from his question.

Comment: It is the default behavior of devices called "access points".

Comment: @trent In the first sentence: `wireless G access point in a central location in the house and I have had wireless disabled on my router` - the AP is unlikely to be the gateway.